# Mail server on port 25 only response with 500 command not recognized

Tags: exchange, cisco, smtp, mx-record

There is a mail server that I'm trying to test using telnet. I telnet to the server on the port and it responses with "220 **************************************************************************"
The server is exchange and sending of mail requires authentication.

When I enter the command "helo" I get "500 5.3.3 Unrecognized command"
no matter what I enter, even "quit" I get the same response. The website MXToolbox (http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx) says that the mail server is responding properly.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the response truly is

```
220 ******************************************
```

then the answer is that, contrary to what you might think, you are **not** talking to a Microsoft Exchange SMTP server.

Rather, [you're talking to a Cisco router with the "mailguard" mechanism enabled](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320027), as Microsoft explains to those who think that they have Exchange problems.  [As Cisco says](http://cisco.com./en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_tech_note09186a00800b2ecb.shtml#howworks), if you want to talk to a Microsoft Exchange server — or to any other server that requires SMTP extensions such as SMTP AUTH, for that matter — you must disable the "mailguard" mechanism and let the world talk to your actual server.

Comment: So then, how is mxtoolbox.com able to communicate with it properly?

Comment: It's not exclusive to Cisco, although Cisco does respond with that. I think WatchGuard and/or SonicWall also utilize similar responses along with other SMTP proxies.

Comment: Untrue.  WatchGuard responds `220 SMTP service ready` and SonicWall responds `220 smtp.example.com SMTP SonicWALL (w.x.y.z)`.  Of the three, it is only Cisco routers that respond with the asterisks.

Comment: mxtoolbox doesn't perform a full SMTP transaction, and isn't the acid test that you think it to be.

Comment: What if I can connect fine from a Linux telnet session, but am getting the "500 unrecognized command" only from a Windows telnet session? Is that still explained by the mailguard issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are more than likely running into a SMTP proxy, either on the router or firewall.

Comment: "So then, how is mxtoolbox.com able to communicate with it properly?" It may be set to ESMTP-only in which case it would be "ehlo" instead of the "helo" command string.