# Getting error 500 when sending 1st command to Exchange

Tags: exchange, smtp, sonicwall

It is **NOT** a duplicate of this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/838172/getting-500-unrecognized-command-when-telnet-to-mail-server-from-windows-wor) because I do **NOT** have any CISCO device. I have

- an HP PS1810-24G Switch
- a SonicWALL TZ 105 firewall.

So, in the post and other links not one of any suggestions can be applied.

The strange thing is:

- **Only the first command is rejected - usually `EHLO servername`**.
- The **following commands are executed correctly**, even I resend `EHLO servername`.

When I connect to the Exchange **behind** the firewall, then even the first command is executed immediately.

I was checking my SonicWALL for 1 hour, I opened each available menu/option but I didn't find anything regarding this. Also, in the internet there is no word regarding this.

Any idea what I can do?

The screenshot from the communication:

[image]

Comment: "When I connect to the Exchange behind the firewall, then even the first command is executed immediately." - sounds like you know the issue stems from some interaction with the Sonicwall.  Have you reached out to their support?

Comment: @TheCleaner I don't have a support ticket and they want to charge me for this - even they don't know if they can fix it - 250 USD.

Comment: It's my understanding that the SMTP communication may be blocked by the firewall. Allow it. The issue is related to SonicWALL, if it doesn't work, better contact them for professional help.

Comment: @BeverlyGao I added a screenshot. Check it. The SMTP communication is not blocked. Only the first command isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

Set PuTTY's Telnet negotiation mode to Passive.
[PuTTY settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoFR7.png)

Comment: OK my friend, upvoted for this idea. Indeed, changing it to `Passive mode` fixes this but only **under** PuTTY. How can I fix it for example under PHP when connecting to the Exchange?